# Pull account data by url data

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Okay im trying to make it so that user pages can be accessed by things entered in the url field

I have been going through this youtube tutorial and it seems to be helping quite a bit

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsgnKTuQeMw&feature=relmfu

But I still have a issue with getting it to work

And also would love to be able to change it up a bit.

Here is the code im using in the include file

```
<?php
$db_name ="data"; /** The name of the database for this install */
$dbusername = "data"; /** MySQL database username */
$dbpassword = "data@"; /** MySQL database password */ 
$server = "data.m"; //** Probably don't need to change     this */

 $connection = mysql_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
 $db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection)or die(mysql_error());    



function fetch_user_info($AccountNumber){


 $sql = "SELECT
`FirstName` AS `FirstName`,
`LastName` AS `LastName`,
`Gender` AS `Gender`,
`City` AS `City`,
`State` AS `State`,
`AccountNumber` AS `AccountNumber`
 FROM `content`
 WHERE `content` = {$AccountNumber}";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


 }
?>
```

That is the include file should be declaring the function and connecting to my mysql server

And here is the code for the profile template

```
<?php

 include "config.php";

  $user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['AccountNumber']);
  print_r($user_info);
 ?>
```

So basicly what I want this to do is return all the data on something like

http://www.MyDomain.Com/Profile.php?AccountNumber=50b05fed59e54

Not sure where I have gone wrong

Any help is much appreciated and would be awsome to finnnaly have my site online the only other thing I dream of is finding a way to make the url something more like
http://www.MyDomain.Com/Profile.php?FirstName_LastName_50b05fed59e54

Another words make my urls include my users first and last name not sure if that is possible without anything to complicated but thank you for everything.

Here is my error part of the setup file

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/34/9587634/html/MYDOMAIN/config.php on line 27
```

Comment: why you are comparing account number against content in your where clause in your query......

Comment: You don't say what error you are getting - is the query returning anything?

Comment: OO im sorry Ill edit sorry spaced it

Comment: Seems to me your query is failing: Manual states: For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error. I'm guessing you are getting FALSE

Comment: hmm not quite sure what you mean???

Comment: you can try the following: Echo the $sql variable to the browser, and try and run it manually in the database. See if you get errors. Or... check whether $result === false before calling mysql_fetch_assoc. I'm guessing it's an error in the query. Try putting {$AccountNumber} between single quotes like '{$AccountNumber}'

Comment: also... as Venkat noticed, you seem to be comparing AccountNumber to the Content column in the database, which seems rather strange.

Comment: Got it thank you It was me comparing it to the wrong comlum I hate it when I confuse variables cause im trying to change them from the tut but thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you have those curly brackets in the query?

Also try dumping (with var_dump() ) the result of the query in order to debug where the issue is.

If the query and its result are fine, then move to the next line and so on and so forth till you find your error.

Try for the argument's sake with mysql_fetch_array() instead.

And lastly, but not least: I'm not entirely sure print_r will work in this syntax.. You can Try echoing each element separately, just to make sure the info gets fetched from the DB by using echo $user_info['FirstName'] for an instance..

Cheers!